# Custom page with products where attribute is equal to

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.7

I'm looking for a way to show a **custom page with products** on it. This is the case:

In an older version of the webshop there were 2 pages. The first one was *'promoties.html'* for Dutch and *'promotions.html'* for English. They were in the table **pp_core_url_rewrite** like this:

[image]

The **category 13** was a category named **promotion** and all linked products to this category where promotion products.

The categories in the new version are changed and we **don't have promotion category anymore**. We can now set an **attribute** named **promotion** of an article to **true** or **false**.

[image]

But now I would like to know how I can make the promotion pages work again with selecting all the products where the attribute promotion is true. But I don't really know how to start with this, can anybody help me on my way?

Comment: Why not re-create a promotion category and assign it to all of the promotion products (could be done using the mass product update). Then you could reuse your existing rewrite?

Answer (score 0):

As i think you know how to create product attribute using admin panel in magento. Create a promotion attribute of a product first .Then Using the query update the product attribute to true or false in previously created products as required .Then you can show the products on the basis of that attribute in promotion pages store wise.